# jquery slideToggle doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of events, and what I'm trying to do, is that when the user clicks one of the event, the event name box would expand and the description from the event should appear under the event name, but currently it just closes the next event instead.

Here is my jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.event_hide').hide();
            jQuery('.eventr').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.next("div").slideToggle(500);
            });
        });
```

Here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Cxx2/76/

Hope you can help me out.

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for It is a descendant element not the next sibling of the clicked `eventr` element, use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$this.find(".event_hide").slideToggle(500);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HWdDW/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$this.find(".event_hide").slideToggle(500);`

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/9Cxx2/77/

Answer (score 0):

Use **.find(".event_hide")** in place of **.next("div")** like,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.event_hide').hide();
    jQuery('.eventr').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find(".event_hide").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Read [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/KdyCV/)